# create a max datatype without inserting a variable

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I would like to create a maximum (sufficiently big) datatype and I want the memory to be allocated to that new variable without me trying to to insert something in it. I need it for testing purposes.

I was thinking I could use

```
varchar(max)
```

But of course var stands for variable and if no value was inserted then it allocates zero memory to my varchar. Then I thought to use just char(max), but that seemed to not work with TSQL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `char(8000)` is the [largest definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) for `char` you're allowed in SQL Server.  However, you're also [limited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) to the row length limit of 8060 bytes.  Variable length fields can get around that.  I'm not sure if fixed length fields do.  I've never had a need to test it.  It wouldn't surprise me if you never get an accurate test with fields full of white space, however.  SQL Server has a lot of optimizations, and that might include whitespace tricks for `char` fields.

Comment: @BaconBits thank you. I will try it. I have an SSIS package that fails when it's transferring a certain amount of columns. I think it has something to do with the memory that the rows take. That's why I need an easy way to insert a specific amount of memory into the table and test the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After BaconBits suggestion I ended up using:

```
char(7000)
```

Seems like 7,000 is the highest definition for a char in tsql. The maximum allowable table row size is 8060 bytes and you also need to account for 7 bytes of internal overhead.

Outside the scope of the question:
When I tried char(7001) it failed saying, "creating or altering table 'myTest' failed because the minimum row size would be 14810, including 7 bytes of internal overhead. This exceeds the maximum allowable table row size of 8060 bytes". I think the compiler is doing things that it is not telling us because 7001 bytes plus 7 bytes of overhead is not bigger then 8060 bytes.

Comment: Have you got other fields in the table?  That would make it larger than the 8k limit.  Something like `create table #test ( field char(8000) not null )` should work just fine, though.  Not sure why adding one character increases the row size so much, though.

Comment: @BaconBits yes I have another field in the table. It's name_char and it is of the type char(1). Just for the sheer of curiosity I deleted name_char and then tried to change my only column to char(6000) which worked for the first time. Then I tried to change it to char(7000) and it didn't work. I then tried char(5000) and it worked. Finally I tried char(6000) again and I got an error. Seems like it's dynamic, but I have no idea how it is determined and why it's done this way. :(

Comment: That's just bizzare. I wonder if it has to do with how the table is getting stored on disk?  Like perhaps [the rows would be spanning a cluster](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814(v=sql.100).aspx)?

Comment: @BaconBits honestly I wouldn't know. Maybe. I guess you haven't seen anything like that?

Comment: No, I haven't. To be fair, I've never needed a `char` that large.  I created about half a dozen temp tables with a single `char(8000)` field on SQL Server 2008 R2, and never got a single error.  I'm also confused why you'd get a complaint about the row size being almost 14k when the rows weren't that long.  All I can think of it disk alignment to clusters, or possibly different text encoding if your server locale is not the default.